# HTML error reverses itself: <button> in <a>, <a> in <button>

Tags: html, hyperlink

My team and I are currently developing a website, but we are having an error with validation. The W3C validator said that the `button` cannot be a child of `a`, so we reversed it so `a` was a child of `button`. Then the validator said that `a` cannot be a child of `button`.

How could we fix this so it validates? We also tried creating a `.button` CSS class and put it in `a` (removing the `button` tags), but this messed up all formatting of the page.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="column">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="images/tow.png" alt="Mike" style="width:100%">
          <div class="container">
            <h4>Trials of Wizardry</h4>
            <p>Some text that describes me lorem ipsum ipsum lorem.</p>
            <p><button class="button"><a href="http://store.steampowered.com">Buy Now!!</a></button></p>
           </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot have a link inside of a button. This does not make sense as if you think about it, a `<button>` is an interactive element that's supposed to "do something". An anchor element `<a>` is also an interactive element supposed to take the user somewhere. If you nest the two you have two interaction within the same element. If you want the button style on the link you need to do the following

`<p><a href="http://store.steampowered.com" class="button">Buy Now!!</a></p>`